# SQL(plus) performance with sequence

Tags: performance, oracle, plsql, code-generation, sequence

I have to generate some million update from some table, to update themselves. I had just recently learned about `parallel(tablename,threads)` which really improved the performance in PLSQL developer when I had run something like this:

```
select /* + parallel(table1,100) parallel(table2,100) */
       'update table1 set id = 1 where ... and id = '||table1.id||' ...
where ...
```

(I'm doing it like this, because it gives me the backup data in the update. And my BOSS told me to do it like this ;-))

So it really worked fast when using a static number in the `set id = 1` part and in PLSQL Developer.

But then I wrote it to a file, and inserted a `create sequence` before, and tried to use the sequence as follows:

```
create sequence myseq
 start with   4200000
 increment by 1
 maxvalue     11200000;


select /* + parallel(table1,100) parallel(table2,100) */
       'update table1 set id = '||myseq.nextval||' where ... and id = '||table1.id||' ...
where ...
```

But now it's terribly slow. And I don't know why. I just rewrote the `update` generator, to insert static data in there, and used `awk` to replace that with a sequence of numbers, but could someone explain what had caused this (and can I do something about it)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sequences can be quite a bottleneck, especially when multiple sessions/threads are using them at once.

The main thing you can do to improve this is to increase the number of sequence values that are cached:  `ALTER SEQUENCE CACHE n`, replacing `n` with a value greater than 20 (the default).  I would suggest setting it much higher since you will be using many or all of the sequence values in one statement.  You can go as high as `(CEIL (MAXVALUE - MINVALUE)) / ABS (INCREMENT)`.

Comment: +1.  In addition to trying to make sequences work better with multiple threads, have you considered using less parallelism?  Why did you use 100 instead of the Oracle default?  You may actually be using 200 sessions if your query has any grouping or ordering.  (Check v$px_process to see how many parallel sessions you are using).  Does your database have dozens of cores and disks?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dave (and all of you guys). I'm on a test server with 16 GB RAM, and 16 cores. Several disks as well. What I did is run the query without sequence, and it finished in e.g. 5 minutes (spooled output into a file). Then added the sequence, withc `CACHE 20000` and monitored the line growth of output via `watch -d wc -l output.sql`. 5 minutes later it still showed ~1000 lines, which means it had used only ~150 `nextval`s.